# Passing A Generic List

Tags: c#, list, winforms, generics

I am trying to pass a generic list and I am getting the following error:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PersonManager.Client>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<PersonManager.Client>>'

```
public static bool FillDropDownBox<T>(ComboBox box, List<T> list, string displayMember, string valueMember) where T:List<T>
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        box.Items.Clear();
        box.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());                
        box.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        box.ValueMember = valueMember;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug("List is empty");
        return false;
    }            
}

public static List<Client> ClientList = new List<Client>();


public static void FillClientBox(ComboBox box, Control control)
{
    if(FillDropDownBox<List<Client>>(box, ClientList, "Nickname", "Id")){
}
```

}

Solution code:

```
public static bool FillDropDownBox<T>(ComboBox box, List<T> list, string displayMember, string valueMember) where T:class
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                box.Items.Clear();
                box.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());                
                box.DisplayMember = displayMember;
                box.ValueMember = valueMember;
                box.SelectedIndex = 0;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug("List is empty");
                return false;
            }            
        }

        public static void FillClientBox(ComboBox box, Control control)
        {
            if(FillDropDownBox(box, ClientList, "Nickname", "Id"))          
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: There method taking a generic list in your code.

Comment: why would you restrict `T` to be a list? `where T:List<T>` ? the generic parameter should specify the type of the items of the list. Or do you really want to have a list of lists ?

Comment: please post the declaration of `ClientList` and its type

Comment: public static List<Client> ClientList = new List<Client>();

Comment: please revert your last edit and rather add the new code below the original. Because now the problem cannot be reproduced from the posted code! this is very confusing for future visitors, and it renders the answers obsolete. I took the liberty to rollback the changes.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method:

```
public static bool FillDropDownBox<T>(ComboBox box, List<T> list, string displayMember, string valueMember) where T:List<T>
```

`T` specifies the type of object that populates the `List` and you restrict it to be a list of lists!

So when you call it you specify it as the entire list, but you pass only a normal list which I assume is a `List<Client>`:

```
FillDropDownBox<List<Client>>(box, ClientList, "Nickname", "Id")
```

so the compiler expects a list of lists! that is your problem.

change the restriction to `where T:class`

Actually you should be able to remove the explicit declaration at all and the compiler can infer the type from the passed list `ClientList`

```
public static void FillClientBox(ComboBox box, Control control)
{
    if(FillDropDownBox(box, ClientList, "Nickname", "Id")){
}
```

Comment: Hi I get an error:
CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T[]' to 'object[]'
for the line:
 box.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());

Comment: @Nuvolari I don't know what you changed. Did you simply remove the restriction? or did you change it to `where T:class` ?

Comment: I updated the code to what you said. I'll update my post

Comment: you need to change it, if you remove the restriction than the implicit conversion to `object` does not work

Comment: Ok where T : class on the end worked. Thx Mong

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do this:

```
public static bool FillDropDownBox<T>(ComboBox box, List<T> list, string displayMember, string valueMember)
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        box.Items.Clear();
        box.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
        box.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        box.ValueMember = valueMember;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug("List is empty");
        return false;
    }
}

public static void FillClientBox(ComboBox box, Control control)
{
    if (FillDropDownBox<Client>(box, ClientList, "Nickname", "Id"))
    {
    }
}
```

Because the parameter is a `List<T>` you do not need to constrain `T`.

And when you call `FillDropDownBox` you just need to specify the type - if you specify it as `List<Client>` then you're saying that the `list` parameter is `List<List<Client>>`.